# progressbar does not change visibility after orientation change

Tags: android, screen-orientation, rx-android, activity-lifecycle, rx-java2

i have been stuck with this problem for two days now and still don't know what the problem is. I'm observing the lifecycle events of an activity. I combine rxLifecycle observable with test observable using combineLatest. The combinedResultObservable is subscribed after button click and a progressBar is shown. After this observable is disposed, the progressbar is not shown anymore.
It is working correctly. But when screen orientation changes, the progressBar does not change visibility to View.GONE even though the log statements are printing correctly. Notice in the code

```
.doOnDispose(() ->{
                progressBarIsShowing = false;
                mRetainedFragment.setProgressBarIsShowing(progressBarIsShowing);
                log("doondispose");
                findViewById(R.id.progressBar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                log("doondispose2");
            })
```

doondispose and doondispose2 is printing correctly but the line inbetween 
findViewById(R.id.progressBar).setVisibility(View.GONE); is not working.
Please take a look and help me solve this.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LifeCycleEventListener {


LifeCycleEventListener lifeCycleEventListener = this;
private CombinedResult combinedResult;
private ObservableEmitter<String> eventEmitter = new ObservableEmitter<String>() {
    @Override
    public void setDisposable(Disposable d) {

    }

    @Override
    public void setCancellable(Cancellable c) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isDisposed() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public ObservableEmitter<String> serialize() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(@NonNull String value) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(@NonNull Throwable error) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {

    }
};
private Observable<String> rxLifecycle = Observable.create(e -> {
    e.onNext("onResume");
    eventEmitter = e;
});

private Observable<Integer> test = Observable.create(e -> {
    try {
        e.onNext(-1);
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
            Thread.sleep(500);
            if (i == 24) {
                e.onNext(i);
            }
        }
        e.onComplete();
    } catch (Exception x) {
        e.onError(x);
    }
});

private Disposable disposable;
boolean progressBarIsShowing;
private static final String TAG_RETAINED_FRAGMENT = "RetainedFragment";

private RetainedFragment mRetainedFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    mRetainedFragment = (RetainedFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(TAG_RETAINED_FRAGMENT);

    if (mRetainedFragment == null) {

        mRetainedFragment = new RetainedFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(mRetainedFragment, TAG_RETAINED_FRAGMENT).commit();
        mRetainedFragment.setLifeCycleEventListener(lifeCycleEventListener);
        mRetainedFragment.setEventEmitter(eventEmitter);
        mRetainedFragment.setRxLifecycle(rxLifecycle);
        if (progressBarIsShowing) {
            findViewById(R.id.progressBar).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            findViewById(R.id.progressBar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("myapp","dhukse");
        lifeCycleEventListener = mRetainedFragment.getLifeCycleEventListener();
        eventEmitter = mRetainedFragment.getEventEmitter();
        rxLifecycle = mRetainedFragment.getRxLifecycle();
        progressBarIsShowing = mRetainedFragment.isProgressBarIsShowing();
        disposable = mRetainedFragment.getDisposable();
        if (progressBarIsShowing) {
            findViewById(R.id.progressBar).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            findViewById(R.id.progressBar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }


    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(v -> start());
    lifeCycleEventListener.emitEvent("onCreate");
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    lifeCycleEventListener.emitEvent("onStart");
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    lifeCycleEventListener.emitEvent("onResume");
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    lifeCycleEventListener.emitEvent("onPause");
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    lifeCycleEventListener.emitEvent("onStop");

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    lifeCycleEventListener.emitEvent("onDestroy");
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (!progressBarIsShowing) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().remove(mRetainedFragment).commit();
    }
    else{
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }
}

private void start() {
    findViewById(R.id.progressBar).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    progressBarIsShowing = true;
    mRetainedFragment.setProgressBarIsShowing(progressBarIsShowing);

    Observable<CombinedResult> combinedResultObservable = Observable.combineLatest(rxLifecycle, test, this::getCombinedResult);
    combinedResultObservable
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .doOnNext(this::setResult)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnDispose(() ->{
                progressBarIsShowing = false;
                mRetainedFragment.setProgressBarIsShowing(progressBarIsShowing);
                log("doondispose");
                findViewById(R.id.progressBar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                log("doondispose2");
            })
            .subscribe(new Observer<CombinedResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                    disposable = d;
                    mRetainedFragment.setDisposable(disposable);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(CombinedResult combinedResult) {
                    log(combinedResult.getLifeEvent() + ":" + combinedResult.getUser());
                    if (combinedResult.getUser() == 24) {
                        progressBarIsShowing = false;
                        mRetainedFragment.setProgressBarIsShowing(progressBarIsShowing);
                        findViewById(R.id.progressBar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        checkResult();
                        disposable.dispose();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    progressBarIsShowing = false;
                    mRetainedFragment.setProgressBarIsShowing(progressBarIsShowing);
                    findViewById(R.id.progressBar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            });


}

private void checkResult() {
    if (combinedResult.getUser() == 24) {
        progressBarIsShowing = false;
        mRetainedFragment.setProgressBarIsShowing(progressBarIsShowing);
        findViewById(R.id.progressBar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        log("successful");
    }
}

private void setResult(CombinedResult combinedResult) {
    this.combinedResult = combinedResult;
}

private class CombinedResult {
    private String lifeEvent;
    private Integer user;

    CombinedResult(String lifeEvent, Integer user) {
        this.lifeEvent = lifeEvent;
        this.user = user;
    }

    String getLifeEvent() {
        return lifeEvent;
    }

    Integer getUser() {
        return user;
    }
}

private CombinedResult getCombinedResult(String lifeEvent, Integer user) {
    return new CombinedResult(lifeEvent, user);
}

private void log(String s) {
    Log.e("myapp", s);
}

@Override
public void emitEvent(String event) {

    eventEmitter.onNext(event);

}
}
```

The fragment for saving Activity instance in case of config change RetainedFragment.java

```
public class RetainedFragment extends Fragment {


private LifeCycleEventListener lifeCycleEventListener;
private ObservableEmitter<String> eventEmitter;
private Observable<String> rxLifecycle;
private boolean progressBarIsShowing;
private Disposable disposable;
public RetainedFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // retain this fragment
    setRetainInstance(true);
}

public LifeCycleEventListener getLifeCycleEventListener() {
    return lifeCycleEventListener;
}

public void setLifeCycleEventListener(LifeCycleEventListener lifeCycleEventListener) {
    this.lifeCycleEventListener = lifeCycleEventListener;
}

public ObservableEmitter<String> getEventEmitter() {
    return eventEmitter;
}

public void setEventEmitter(ObservableEmitter<String> eventEmitter) {
    this.eventEmitter = eventEmitter;
}

public boolean isProgressBarIsShowing() {
    return progressBarIsShowing;
}

public void setProgressBarIsShowing(boolean progressBarIsShowing) {
    this.progressBarIsShowing = progressBarIsShowing;
}

public Observable<String> getRxLifecycle() {
    return rxLifecycle;
}

public void setRxLifecycle(Observable<String> rxLifecycle) {
    this.rxLifecycle = rxLifecycle;
}

public Disposable getDisposable() {
    return disposable;
}

public void setDisposable(Disposable disposable) {
    this.disposable = disposable;
}
}
```

Interface for lifecycle change LifeCycleEventListener.java

```
public interface LifeCycleEventListener {
void emitEvent(String event);
}
```

In case anyone is wondering there is something wrong with the layout
activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.fahim.rxlifecycle.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:text="@string/start"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="109dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:id="@+id/button" />

<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_marginStart="44dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The logcat after button press

```
E/myapp: onResume:-1
```

(after changing orientation)

```
E/myapp: dhukse
E/myapp: onPause:-1
E/myapp: onStop:-1
E/myapp: onDestroy:-1
E/myapp: onCreate:-1
E/myapp: onStart:-1
E/myapp: onResume:-1
E/myapp: onResume:24
E/myapp: successful
```

(after disposing)

```
E/myapp: doondispose
E/myapp: doondispose2
```

In the end the progressbar is still visible. Please help me someone.

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this problem because when the orientation change the android system kill the activity and if you are saving the activity state (like your doing) you can get the activity data.

Now the problem is when orientation change happens and you are retaing the activity state that time you are getting old object of progress bar. but you are setting visibilty on new object `findViewById(R.id.progressBar).setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Declare a global varaible for progress bar

```
ProgressBar progressBar;
```

Now initaliize in onCreate method

```
progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
```

Now set visibility for this object according to your conditions.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I did as you said. But no success. ProgressBar still visible. I also saved the progressBar object in fragment(which is not good) but doing so made the progressbar gone right after orientation change before the combine observable was disposed.